# Issues using ffmpeg and easy screen: Pipe is broken

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I am trying to record my screen using easy screen. I think it uses a CLI tool called `ffmpeg` and just provides us with a GUI to use the CLI version. Am I correct in thinking this?

Anyway, when I try to record my screen I get a error screen

```
ffmpeg version 2020-12-15-git-32586a42da-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 93.100 /  7. 93.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from '\\.\pipe\captura-fe91177e-9004-4cd3-96f9-3111a2b67705':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 335708 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 1366x768, 335708 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
C:\Users\44746\Documents\EasyScreen\2020-12-18-07-46-39.mp4: Permission denied
```

The other error screen shows this (PIPE IS BROKEN)

```
System.IO.IOException: Pipe is broken.
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.BeginWriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_0(Stream stream, ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInstance thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)
   at System.IO.Stream.BeginEndWriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Stream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Captura.Models.FFmpegWriter.WriteFrame(IBitmapFrame Frame)
   at Captura.Models.WithPreviewWriter.WriteFrame(IBitmapFrame Image)
   at Screna.Recorder.DoWrite()
```

Do you think I just need to run as admin? How would I get easy screen to run as admin in the CLI if so?

Or do you think I should just give up with this GUI nonsense and stick to PowerShell?

(I mean, this code looks like it is trying to pipe in the next set of commands but failing due to lack of admin privileges... Does that make sense?)

Comment: Which "easy screen" do you mean; this one? https://easyscreen.me/

Comment: The error message seems to be about a file in your own home directory so _probably_ not fixable by switching to admin. Do the directories exist? If not, try to create them first. If they do, does this file already exist there with write protection or something?

Comment: Can you explain why you rolled back my edit?

Comment: This looks to be an EasyScreen issue.

Comment: Yeah it was an easy screen issue, you are right! I just used the CLI got the job done much quicker lol. Think I finally need to just break off having my hand held by GUI all the time and start living in the CLI only. It seems to fix all!

Comment: triplee I am new to stackflow, I don't even know what roll back is! So sorry if I stepped on toes, wasn't intentional :D